# Creating a method in JAVA to print the content of an ArrayList calling a specific format of another class

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

In this example, I would like to add students of a school into an ArrayList and print the array list with Polymorphism format from another method defined in another class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Student{
   public static String name;
   public static String gender;
   public static int age;

   //setting default values for the member variables
   public Student(){
       name = "default name";
       gender = "default gender";
       age = 0;
   }    

  //constructor of the parameters for the name, gender, and age.
   public Student(String name, String gender, int age){
       Student.name = name;
       Student.gender = gender;
       Student.age = age;
   }

   // Polymorphism to print with a specific format
   public static void printInfo(){
       System.out.println(name+", "+gender+", "+age+"\n");
   }
}

// creating a class for Male students
class Male extends Student{
    private static String gender;

    public Male(String name, int age){
        super(name, gender, age);

        Male.gender = "Male";
    }
}

// creating a class for Female students
class Female extends Student{
    private static String gender;

    public Female(String name, int age){
        super(name, gender, age);

        Female.gender = "Female";
    }
}

// create a class for school to collect all the students
class School{
      static ArrayList<Student> students;
      public static void addStudent(Student a){
          ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
          students.add(a);
      }
      public void printAllInfo(){
         //call the Student.printInfo method from the Student class
      }
}

public class SchoolBuilder{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       School.addStudent(new Male("Sam",13));
       School.addStudent(new Male("John",11));
       School.addStudent(new Female("Elle",12));
       School.addStudent(new Male("Paul",12));
       School.addStudent(new Female("Javinia",11));
       School.addStudent(new Male("Paperino",12));

       //PRint all by calling School.printAllInfo should print the formatted ArrayList 
    }
}
```

The output should be like this:

```
  Sam, Male, 13
  John, Male, 11
  Elle, Female, 12
  Paul, Male, 12
  Javinia, Female, 11
  Paperino, Male, 12
```

I am new to JAVA and just can't figure out how to do it. It seems like it's easy.
I've made the two classes for gender because it is easy to add later a CSV file of all males or females and add them into the dataset calling the male and female classes respectively.

Thanks for your time and help with this.

Comment: You're misusing statics.  `Student` should not have static members, because that means that there is only one name, one gender, and one age for **all** students.  Every time you modify one of those values for one student, it changes it for all of them.  In general, it's almost always wrong to use statics.  They should only be used when a value or method should be exactly the same for every single instance of a class.

Comment: Override `toString()` and it will automatically print whatever you implement in that method.

Answer (score 2):

In general, we do this by overriding the `toString()` method of some class, and then printing that.

Take the following as constructive criticism: there are a bunch of issues here.

1. You want to avoid the static context in this case, because static
   variables belong to a class. Not every student will have the same
   name, for example.
2. Similarly, you wouldn't call `Student.function()`, you would call `this.function()` to call that for only that student, not the class student. `this` is an instance of Student.
3. You definitely don't want to do `ArrayList<Student> students = new
   ArrayList<Student>();` within your addStudent() method. You're
   resetting your list of students every time you add a student. Keep
   that in the class level declaration or better yet, add a
   constructor.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Student{
   public String name;
   public String gender;
   public int age;

   //setting default values for the member variables
   public Student(){
       name = "default name";
       gender = "default gender";
       age = 0;
   }    

  //constructor of the parameters for the name, gender, and age.
   public Student(String name, String gender, int age){
       this.name = name;
       this.gender = gender;
       this.age = age;
   }


   // Polymorphism to print with a specific format
   public String printInfo(){
       return name+", "+gender+", "+age+"\n";
   }
}

// creating a class for Male students
class Male extends Student{
    private static String gender;

    public Male(String name, int age){
        super(name, gender, age);

        Male.gender = "Male";
    }
}

// creating a class for Female students
class Female extends Student{
    private static String gender;

    public Female(String name, int age){
        super(name, gender, age);

        Female.gender = "Female";
    }
}

// create a class for school to collect all the students
class School{
      ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

      public void addStudent(Student a) {
          students.add(a);
      }

      public void printAllInfo(){
         //call the Student.printInfo method from the Student class
      }

      public String toString() {
          String string = "";

          for (Student s : students) {
              string += s.printInfo();
          }

          return string;
      }
}

public class Work{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        School sch = new School();

       sch.addStudent(new Male("Sam",13));
       sch.addStudent(new Male("John",11));
       sch.addStudent(new Female("Elle",12));
       sch.addStudent(new Male("Paul",12));
       sch.addStudent(new Female("Javinia",11));
       sch.addStudent(new Male("Paperino",12));

       System.out.println(sch.toString()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be class Male, same is for Female:

```
        // creating a class for Male students
class Male extends Student{
    private static final String gender = "Male";//This should be constant for all instances of class and because of that it is "static final"

    public Male(String name, int age){
        super(name, gender, age);
    }
}
```

Next School would not have any static thing in it.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

// create a class for school to collect all the students
class School {
    private ArrayList<Student> students; //Should not be static, and initialization moved in constructor

    public School() {
        students = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student a) {
        students.add(a);
    }

    public void printAllInfo() {
        for (Student s : students) {
            s.printInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally main class should create School instance, add students and print them:

```
public class SchoolBuilder{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        School school=new School();
        school.addStudent(new Male("Sam",13));
        school.addStudent(new Male("John",11));
        school.addStudent(new Female("Elle",12));
        school.addStudent(new Male("Paul",12));
        school.addStudent(new Female("Javinia",11));
        school.addStudent(new Male("Paperino",12));

        school.printAllInfo();
    }
}
```

Last, this method in Student should not have \n in String as it will add one more new line.

```
    // Polymorphism to print with a specific format
public void printInfo(){
    System.out.println(name+", "+gender+", "+age+"\n");
}
```

Comment: ```static``` means that is a field of the class, not the object. If you want that the field doesn't change value, it has to be only ```final```.

Comment: Yes, A. Wolf is right, final is only needed for variable to become constant. Static final is because this is constant that should be used for all instances of this class. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There are some error in your implementation:

1. The `Student` object should not has `static` fields. `static` means that they're not referred to a specific object, but to the class itself.
   The object is a specific implementation of a class. You define a `Student` class to define how a student looks like, that with a specific instatiation you create a student. 
   When you declare the class, you say that a student has in general a name, gender and age.
   When you istantiate a student with the constructor (`new Student("Sam", "Male", 13)`) you define the specific implementation.

```
 class Student {
      public String name;
        public String gender;
        public int age;

        //setting default values for the member variables
        public Student(){
            name = "default name";
            gender = "default gender";
            age = 0;
        }    

       //constructor of the parameters for the name, gender, and age.
        public Student(String name, String gender, int age){
            this.name = name;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.age = age;
        }
```

2. Class `Male` and `Female` has to be changed. It's not wrong to extend the `Student` class to set a default value to the `gender` field. It would be more useful to extend it if, for example, the `Male` class has a specific field (for example `favouriteSoccerPlayer`) which instead a general student should not have. In that case the `Male` class would inherit the fields from the parent class (`Student`) and add another extra field:

```
    class Male extends Student {
            private String favouriteSoccerPlayer;

       public Male(String name,  int age) {
           super(name, "Male", age); // call the constructor of the super class
       }
       public Male(String name,  int age, String favouriteSoccerPlayer) {
           super(name, "Male", age); // call the constructor of the super class
           this.favouriteSoccerPlayer = favouriteSoccerPlayer;
       }

       // getter and setter for only this field
    }
```

then you can for example do something like this:

```
Male male = new Male("John", 32, "Maradona");
System.out.println(male.getName());
```

and you'll call the method that the `Male` object inherit from the `Student` class.